# Powershell script to get only branchcache status

Tags: powershell

I trying to get Branch cache status from the console but have been unable to do so

There is a command Get-BCStatus that returns a lot data below

Get-BCStatus

BranchCacheIsEnabled        : False
BranchCacheServiceStatus    : Stopped
BranchCacheServiceStartType : Manual

ClientConfiguration:

```
CurrentClientMode           : Disabled
HostedCacheServerList       : 
HostedCacheDiscoveryEnabled : False
```

ContentServerConfiguration:

```
ContentServerIsEnabled : False
```

HostedCacheServerConfiguration:

```
HostedCacheServerIsEnabled        : False
ClientAuthenticationMode          : Domain
HostedCacheScpRegistrationEnabled : False
```

I am trying powershell queries but been unsuccessful at it

I just need the status of Branch Cache and nothing else

I tried the query below

```
Get-BCStatus | Where-Object {$_.BranchCacheIsEnabled}
```

I just need False but it returns nil

Comment: You need to wrap it with an `IF/Else` condition on the property BranchCacheIsEnabled. If yes then enabled , else not enabled. What you asked is what you are getting because you are only asking to return data if BranchCacheIsEnabled which if false is gonna result nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get-BCStatus | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BranchCacheIsEnabled`

Just select the one property you want. You were asking powershell to get-BCStatus and then give the ones where the BranchCacheIsEnabled property was not null. But your value was false so the where returned nothing.